# How to multiply the elements in lists with characters and integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, char, integer

input = [1,4,6,"j",5,"h","t"] multiply and add by 2 to the elements in that list
output = [4,10,14,"j",12,"h","t"]
How Can I get That Output In python??

Comment: Do not use `input` as variable name, you're shadowing built-in function. Your problem could be solved with simple list comp `[i * 2 + 2 if isinstance(i, int) else i for i in l]`. Notice, that you can pass a tuple of types into `isinstance()` if you want it to work with *float* as well.

Comment: Thank you soo much ...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `isinstance` like @Olvin Roght showed, or `type()`.

```
new = [num*2+2 if type(num) == int else num for num in inp]
```

output

```
[4, 10, 14, 'j', 12, 'h', 't']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input = [1,4,6,"j",5,"h","t"]
output = []

for idx, item in enumerate(input):
    if type(item) is int:
        item *= 2
        item += 2
    output.append(item)
```

I realize this is significantly more code than the other answers, but I wonder if it is also less efficient...because embedding something inside the [] in python can also be treated as a for loop, right?

Comment: It's slightly less efficient than [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but it's okay. You're using inplace multiplication and addition operators (`*=`, `+=`) which is not the best option here, better *and shorter* will be `item = item * 2 + 2`. Also using `enumerate()` brings no benefit there as you don't need indexes, so you can just iterate over list `for item in input`. And last suggestion: ***do not** use `input` or any other name of built-in function as name of variable, because you're shadowing this function.*

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I understand everything you said except the shadowing. Am I overriding the `input()` function and would I not be able to call it because of the `input` initialization?

Comment: Yes, once you write `input = ...` you shadowing `input()` function and won't be able to call this function.